# initialize firebase emulator storage

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-storage, firebase-tools

is there a way already how to use firebase storage emulator for local development?

I found out it should be possible these days using the firebase-tools I guess but I cant figure out how to include it in my code.

this is my firebase config for localhost

```
import firebase from "firebase/app"
import "firebase/auth"
import "firebase/firestore"
import "firebase/functions"
import "firebase/storage"
import "firebase/database"

 firebase.initializeApp({
   apiKey: "-------------------",
   authDomain: "http://localhost:9099",
   databaseURL: "http://localhost:9000?ns=project-name",
   projectId: "project-name",
   storageBucket: "default-bucket",
   messagingSenderId: "--------------",
   appId: "----------------------",
   measurementId: "-----------------",
})

firebase.firestore().settings({ host: "localhost:8080", ssl: false })
firebase.auth().useEmulator("http://localhost:9099")
firebase.functions().useEmulator("http://localhost5001")
firebase.database().useEmulator("http://localhost:9090")
```

For now when I am trying to store something in the bucket this url is executed:

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/default-bucket/o?name=test-file.csv
```

As I understand it properly, the app is not getting any local storage domain but only the firebase cloud storage domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case somebody will be struggling on the same case.

I was using firebase 8.2.3 and based on SDK availability I was supposed to use firebase 8.4.0 or higher

https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/install_and_configure#client_sdk_availability

Comment: Didn't you use RN SDK for Firebase?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the web sdk v8 you would add it to your code like this:

```js
var storage = firebase.storage();
storage.useEmulator("localhost", 9199);
```

This is outlined in the documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_storage#web-v8

Make sure the storage emulator is running when you run the command `firebase emulators:start` in your terminal

Comment: I have already tried this stuff: Property 'useEmulator' does not exist on type 'Storage'.

Comment: @DahWaR It should work which means there is something wrong with your configuration. Please include the version of the web sdk you're using, as well as additional snippets of code so I can see where you're going wrong.

Comment: I use "firebase": "8.2.3",
"firebase-admin": "^9.4.2"

Comment: I have set the env variable export FIREBASE_STORAGE_EMULATOR_HOST="localhost:9199" as well

Comment: @DahWaR Are you able to share the project so I can look into your issue?

Comment: Did anyone resolve this issue.  I am having same problem.  I am using Firebase CLI version 11.25.3.  I have custom bucket and writing to it will cause the files to go to the cloud instead of the local emulator bucket.